# SSR pages also possible with dynamic elements?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

We want to use SSR (pre-rendered pages) on our site. On the SSR pages we have also dynamic elements like price calculation, calendar with data ect.

Is this possible with SSR ?

best remco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean dynamic routes, you can generate them using `generate.routes` or `nitro.prerender.routes` https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#routes.

For instance, you may have `http://localhost:3000/calendar/01-01-2023`, `http://localhost:3000/calendar/02-01-2023` etc with the date being a dynamic param in the url. With different content for each page, with routes and content coming from a database, an API, a static `.json` file or [`@nuxt/content`](https://content.nuxtjs.org/).

If you mean that the data in the pages change with user interaction, for instance, the price changes when the user adds a product to the shopping chart on a specific route such as `http://localhost:3000/cart`, that is not relevant for pre-render, since the initial render will be with an empty chart with price calculation equal to 0, and it will change dynamically later on.

The example of the cart, may be not perfect, since that page is usually behind a protected route, so you can't generate it, but you may apply the same logic to a public page.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, SSR can realize data dynamics, but it depends on the framework you use to decide how to do it!

Refer to Nuxt data collection:https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching